# How to convert java arraylist to javascript array

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I am working on a Struts MVC project...From Action Java Class I am getting the values as an Arraylist & I have to pass the values directly to a JS Function in JSP in the form of an JavaScript Array...I can I do the same?

Comment: See also ["How to convert java arraylist to javascript array"](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+convert+java+arraylist+to+javascript+array).

Answer (score 2):

Convert the Java `ArrayList` to `JSON` String, and use `JSON.parse()` to get Javascript object.